# When is it required to call git_remote_update_tips?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I've been playing with git fetch functionality similar to the [fetch example](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/fetch.html) for libgit2, but I'm running into some issues. The example as provided does not seem to work for me. Specifically, `git_remote_update_tips` returns -1 and `giterr_last` indicates that this is because I have disconnected from the remote. I tried reordering the calls so `git_remote_update_tips` comes first, but that results in an access violation.

I'm finding the API documentation and the source code to be not very illuminating for me in this regard - I'm just wondering if there is a guideline or good explanation somewhere for exactly what this function does and when I need to call it.

Comment: What code and configuration gets it to segfault? Make sure you're using the latest code from the `development` branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the expectations in a part of the library had changed. The remote heads are now stored until you free the remote so you can update the tips after disconnecting, as in the example, which now works again.

There was also a bug with remote without fetch refspecs, which would segfault in `git_remote_update_tips()` which I'm assuming is what you were using.

Both these issues have been fixed.